# Libre office Calc freezes wile working on a sheet in xlsx format

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, freeze

I'm currently facing an issue where an excel file ocassionally freezes while working on it and applying some vlookup formula to it. I'm not sure if it is an issue with the file itself or in Libre office calc but nevertheless its becoming quite an annoyance now.

When I open the file and start working on it, the file starts to freeze and it freezes the whole system along with it including the mouse pointer movement. At that point, I either have to wait for Libre office to respond or try to force quit it which sometimes doesn't work ultimately forcing me to restart the system.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Libre office calc, tried to do open the file in older version of libreoffice calc, reinstalled the whole os and even tried to use it in libre office calc in windows 10 but there was no relief. The only difference I saw in Windows 10 was that only the file freezed but the OS itself was functional.

I love using Libre office and didn't face any issue whatsoever in the previous files I used. They opened up and worked smoothly so it would be great if we have a workaround for this too. Also, I cannot really share the xlsx file here but I can give some additional details about the file if it helps.

System Specs and version details: 
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8 
Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) 
Disk Capacity: 1.0 TB 
RAM: 7.6 GiB

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 
OS Type:64-bit

Libre Office Calc Version: 6.4.4.2

Excel file Details: 
File Size: 79.8MB 
Count A Rows: 614090 
Cont A Coloumns: 48

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue was the auto save feature in office that periodically saved the file which made the whole system freeze for the duration of the save. Disabling the auto save feature completely solved the issue.